# MongoDB convert group object to key:value (_id:count) object

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have an aggregation pipeline with result like that.

```
[
   {
      "_id":"1621",
      "count":567
   },
   {
      "_id":"1658",
      "count":1089
   }
   ...
]
```

How i can convert this result into key:value pair ("_idValue": "countValue"), like this?

```
   {
      "1621": 567,
      "1658": 1089
      ...
   }
```

My pipeline is:

```
pipeline = [
    {'$match': {
        'date': {'$gte': start_date, '$lt': end_date}
    }},
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$networkId',
            'count': {'$sum': 1}
        }
    },
    {
        '$sort': {'_id': 1}
    },

]
```

Comment: What happens if the id is not unique?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit they are unique

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add below stages after your pipeline stages,

- `$group` by null and construct the array of key-value pair
- `$arrayToObject` convert above formatted array to object
- `$repalceRoot` to replace above converted object to root

```
pipeline = [
  // .. add your pipeline stages here
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      object: {
        $push: { k: "$_id", v: "$count" }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$object" } }
  }
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fpKAnDkgKm_)